# Embed Json Data using mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb with nodejs. I just starting for using mongodb. I have one query.Here is my mongdb Document:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("564dacf84d52785c1d8b4567"),
    "content": "This blog created by karanSofat",
   "html": "<p>This blog created by karanSofat</p>\n",
   "saved_at": ISODate("2015-11-19T11:05:28.618Z"),
   "title": "my blog" 
}
```

I want to make relation with this data. I want my json should like when user comment.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("564dacf84d52785c1d8b4567"),
   "comments": [
     {
       "name": "arpit",
       "email": "arpit@gmail.com",
       "comment": "How can Make we this at good",
       "posted_at": ISODate("2015-11-19T11:06:03.628Z") 
    },
     {
       "name": "sumit",
       "email": "sumit@ggi.net",
       "comment": "this is also well for me",
       "posted_at": ISODate("2015-11-19T11:06:27.172Z") 
    } 
  ],
   "content"▼: "This blog created by karanSofat",
   "html": "<p>This blog created by karanSofat</p>\n",
   "saved_at": ISODate("2015-11-19T11:05:28.618Z"),
   "title": "my blog" 
}
```

I am using angular js and node js.Here is my code:

```
app.post('/comments/:id', function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
var comments = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));



res.json({data:id,data2:input});
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is how can i do in node js.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new mongoose model called comment with the structure:

```
{
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    comment: {
        type: String
    },
    posted_at: {
        type: Date
    }
}
```

Each doc will get assigned it's own unique _id. When you save each comment, update the comments array on your blog_post documents. You can then utilize Mongoose's builtin 'populate' functionality:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: can you please givae an example ?